# Do not mangle name of shared library with Bazel

Tags: c++, build, shared-libraries, bazel

Given a C++ application, built with Bazel, that depends on an external, system provided shared library:

```
cc_binary(
  name = 'app',
  srcs = ['app.cpp'],
  linkstatic = False,
  deps = ['@my_system//:system_lib'],
)
```

The WORKSPACE and BUILD.my_system files:

```
new_local_repository(
  name = 'my_system',
  build_file = 'BUILD.my_system',
  path = '/usr/lib/my_system/',
)
```

```
cc_import(
  name = 'system_lib',
  shared_library = 'system_lib.so',
  visibility = ['//visibility:public'],
)
```

This builds, but first copies the system provided lib to the cache, and links to that:

```
$ ldd bazel-bin/app/app
    system_lib.so => /home/erenon/bazel/proj/bazel-bin/app/../_solib_k8/_U@my_system_S_S_Csystem_Ulib___Uexternal_Smy_system/system_lib.so
    [...]
```

If I move `app` to an identical system that has `/usr/lib/my_system/system_lib.so`, it breaks, as it misses the cache. I'd like to package `app` in a way that it directly links to the original `.so`, without the intermediate cache copy or name mangling, i.e: I'd like to achieve:

```
$ ldd bazel-bin/app/app
    system_lib.so => /usr/lib/my_system/system_lib.so
    [...]
```

I tried `cc_import.system_provided`, but that appears only work for Windows `lib/dll`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your library with another cc_library.
I can't explain why it works, but it does.

```
cc_library(
    name = "libsystem_lib",
    srcs = [ ":system_lib" ],
    hdrs = ...
)
```

Depend on this one instead.